# Is there any example to check code integrity with the help of compiler?

Tags: c, llvm, integrity

Generally, I know that many people hash function codes and sign it for further integrity verification.

So, I am wondering if there is any example that hash codes at compiling stage with the help of compiler (e.g. [hash_combine](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Hashing_8h_source.html) and [hash_code](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Hashing_8h_source.html) in LLVM but I don't know how to use them).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how that would be useful before linking?

Comment: What is that you want to check the integrity of? How do you define the integrity of it?

Comment: I want to first get the hash of function codes and then when our customized runtime execute the program, it will hash the function and compare the result with the one we get at compiling stage. I want to make sure that the codes aren't modified by the attackers. Does that make sense?

Comment: So what is the problem? Build your executable, compute it's hash. Then let the "runtime" compute the hash of it and compare. What does it have to do with compiler?

Comment: I don't want to hash the whole program, just part of it (e.g. some sensitive functions). I guess the compiler might need to get all the instructions in the blocks of the function, hash them and store the result in the executable (I don't want to add extra hash function to the executable or generate another executable only for hashing).

Comment: I really don't get it. Hashing is an external process, *not* something your executable is supposed to do. And partial integrity checking (or authentication, as you eventually will get to it) is a bad idea. Telling from experience.

Comment: My problem is that part of our program will be loaded into arm trustzone (some functions wrapped using trustzone API). And we need to do integrity check inside the trustzone. Therefore, I can't just hash all the executable.

Comment: You need to carefully identify the parts of the executable that need to integrity checked such that the guarantees of the ARM trust zone are intact. This is generally more involved than it seems at the first glance. Maybe you should look at existing frameworks to program for trusted execution environments. Take a look at Microsoft's openenclave. They have an open source implementation of the runtime and the signing tools. [openenclave.io](https://openenclave.io/sdk/)